# apple-app-site-association paths validation

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin.ios, ios-universal-links

Can anyone tell me that what is the issue with my association file, as the link cannot open the app, below is my apple-app-site-association file

```
{
  "applinks":
    {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": "W3H4I4M89M.com.openexample.app",
        "paths": [
                    "/Login"                    
                 ]
      }
    ]
    }
}
```

Comment: The file LGTM. What is the link you're trying to open, and what's in your "associated domains" entitlement?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation from apple regarding deeplinks/ universal linking. Its pretty complete: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/inter-process_communication/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content

Comment: Hi , you also need to do something support be opened in `AppDelegate` .

Comment: I have configured all the necessary things in-app, the only thing is that when I put "*" in paths of apple-app-site-association file. it works fine, the issue occurs when I give specific paths like "/Login" Is it something related to case sensitive paths?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at apple's document about [**adding Universal Links Support to Your Association File**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/inter-process_communication/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/enabling_universal_links?language=objc) .

There is a sample style of file ；

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [{
            "appID": "D3KQX62K1A.com.example.photoapp",
            "paths": ["/albums"]
            },
            {
            "appID": "D3KQX62K1A.com.example.videoapp",
            "paths": ["/videos"]
        }]
    }
}
```

And apple notice that :

> The strings you use to specify website paths in the paths array are case-sensitive.

[image]

**Therefore** , you'd better use lower case to define the **paths** :

```
{
  "applinks":
    {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": "W3H4I4M89M.com.openexample.app",
        "paths": ["/login"]
      }
    ]
    }
}
```